# Why multiple ibeacons are not detecting?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I have used [Demo](https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-iBeacon-Demo) to detect ibeacons near android phone.

But in didRangeBeaconsInRegion() callback never get 2 iBeacons detected. Even one is deactivated and other is activited it gives uuid of previous one.

Let me brief it with an example. One ibeacon is on with uuid(a unique no given to ble chip) 123. Lib is detecting it perfectly fine. Now deactivate 123 and keep on ibecon with uuid 890. But lib is still detecting 123 not 890.

I want to detect all ibeacons near my phone.

Comment: Dhrupal, quite confusing question, can you please b little more clarify please.

Comment: pratik, Edited code. Let me know if my que is still confusing.

Comment: Still confusing, actually I have heard this first time, so May I have some idea about Beacons??

Comment: Just visit the demo. You will get idea.

Comment: Sorry dear, not getting anything, I am sorry I can not help you in this. If you knows something then please share it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used other lib named [AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon). It solved my problem. Now multiple ibeacons get detected .They have given solution for ranging [Ibeacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

If anyone using eclipse than can get lib from [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html) as altbeacon github repository is for gradle build system.